# Order by DESC for DATE Need NULL values to show first

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select *
from tbl1
order by date1 DESC
```

When I do this the null values for `date1` show at the bottom. How do I get them to show at top and then order the ones that have values DESC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using a case expression to determine whether `date1` is null or not and sorting by this first.

```
select *
from tbl1
order by case when date1 is null then 1 else 0 end desc, date1 DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use `isnull`:

```
SELECT ColumnsList
FROM tbl1
ORDER BY ISNULL(date1, '2525-12-31') DESC
```

Comment: I prefer `coalesce()`, but it amounts to the same thing.